# Parameterization for Dropdown in qtp

Tags: qtp, hp-uft

Is it possible to parameterize(Data table method) for Dropdown too?

Guys I have a page called city which contains state (Dropdown) and City Edit field.
State has more than 50,From that I want to add only 10 state and city by using Data driven method.Is it possible to do parameterization for dropdown also (It should pick the values from the global sheet)

Answer (score 0):

Obviously we can. Actually you can include your 10 options as list values and have it selected based on the input you give for iterations.

Try to include list values by accessing the Global datasheet from your local machine where you can access the sheet in excel format.

**Note:** Lemme know if it doesn't work - I have another option too!